# Regex to allow a comma seperated list of codes

Tags: regex

I have an input form which I need to validate, the list must follow these rules

- comma separated
- each code can either

  - begin with a single letter followed by a single underscore only, followed by any number of letters or
  - a group of numbers
- the list must not end with a trailing comma

Valid example data

- A_AAAAA,B_BBBBB,122334,D_DFDFDF
- 12345,123567,123456,A_BBBBB,C_DDDDD,1234567

Invalid example data

- RR_RRR,12345
- 1_111,AVSFFF,
- A_SDDF,,123342

I am using http://www.regexr.com and have got as far as this: [A-Z_]_[A-Z]*,|[0-9]*,

The problem with this is the last code in each valid data example is not selected so the line does not pass the regex pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
^(?:(?:[A-Za-z]_[A-Za-z]*|\d+)(?:,|$))+(?<!,)$
```

[regex101 demo.](https://regex101.com/r/xE6uK8/2)

---

Explanation:

```
^  start of string
(?:  this group matches a single element in the list:
    (?:
        [A-Za-z]  a character
        _         underscore
        [A-Za-z]* any number of characters (including 0)
    | or
        \d+  digits
    )
    (?: followed by either a comma
        ,
    |  or the end of the string
        $
    )
)+  match any number of list elements
(?<!  make sure there's no trailing comma
    ,
)
$  end of string
```

Comment: @user2847098: `the list must not end with a trailing comma` This solution allows the list to end with a trailing comma

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
^(?:[A-Z]_[A-Z]*|[0-9]+)(?:,(?:[A-Z]_[A-Z]*|[0-9]+))*$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mZ5eZ3/3)

Comment: Note that `(token separator)* token` is less efficient than `token (separator token)*`. If the engine fail to match the next `token separator`, it will try for `token` before backtrack one repetition. Check "Regex Debugger" section on these 2 examples on regex101: https://regex101.com/r/zC0xH2/1 https://regex101.com/r/dU7mR3/1

Comment: @nhahtdh cool, that makes sense. My previous regex took 103 steps to match, while the new one takes 83 steps. Updated answer. Thanks :)